# nu validator is ok with unclosed tags

Tags: html, w3c-validation

Why this code is valid with https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea ? 
No `</html>` and `</p>` at the end of the code.
Is it new ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>xxxx</title>


</head>

<body>

  <div class="xxx">xxxxxxxxx</div><br />


  <div class="xx"><a href="xxxx.html">xxxx</a></div>
  <div class="xx"><a href="xxx.html">xxxxx</a></div>
  <div class="xx"><a href="xxx.html">xxx</a></div><br />
  <div class="xx"><a href="xxx.html">xxxxxx</a></div>
  <div class="xx"><a href="xxxx.html">xxxx ?</a></div>
  <div class="xx"><a href="x.html">L'xxx</a></div> <br />
  <div class="xx"><a href="xxxxx.html">xxxxxx</a></div><br />

  <div class="xxx">
    <a href="#"><img src="fichiers/images/img.png" alt="xxxx" class="xxx"></a>

  </div>
  <span class="xxxx">xxxx xxxxx</span>
  <p>
    <img src="xxx/x/xxx.jpg" alt="xxx" class="xxxxx" />

  </p>

  <div class="xxxx">
    <a href="xxxxx.html"><img src="xxx/x/xxxxx.png" alt="xxxx xx" class="xx"></a>
  </div>
  <p>

</body>
```

Comment: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#optional-tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not new. End tags for those elements have been optional since the first version of HTML. The nu validator has got that part of the spec right for as long as I have been using it (as has the previous, DTD based, validator).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Obligatory "this was common knowledge in the 90s" remark from yours truly.